# DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block on manage.py syncdb

Tags: django, postgresql

I cloned an existing django project and set it up on a virtualenv on Windows 10. I installed the following tools;

```
Django==1.5.1
pillow==2.5.1
South==1.0.2
django-autocomplete-light==1.1.7
django-haystack==2.3.1
django-memcache-status==1.1
#django-mptt==0.5.4
mailsnake==1.6.3
psycopg2==2.4.5
requests==1.1.0
simplejson==3.1.0
sorl-thumbnail==11.12
textile==2.1.5
#xapian-haystack==1.1.5beta
gunicorn==19.1.1
#pycurl==7.19.5
django-widget-tweaks==1.3
pycountry==1.10
django-jsonfield==0.9.13
python-dateutil==2.3
geopy==1.7.0
whoosh==2.5.7
structlog==15.1.0
celery==3.1.17
python-memcached==1.54
```

I am using postgresql 9.6.

When I ran python manage.py syncdb I get the above error, interestingly when I comment out all other apps, apps that ship with Django successfully sync.

The following is the error log from pg_log;

```
ERROR:  relation "pages_entrytype" does not exist at character 755
STATEMENT:  SELECT "pages_entrytype"."id", "pages_entrytype"."created", 
"pages_entrytype"."created_by_id", "pages_entrytype"."modified", 
"pages_entrytype"."modified_by_id", "pages_entrytype"."visible", 
"pages_entrytype"."name", "pages_entrytype"."title", 
"pages_entrytype"."header", "pages_entrytype"."description", 
"pages_entrytype"."meta_description", "pages_entrytype"."content", 
"pages_entrytype"."sortorder", "pages_entrytype"."system_required", 
"pages_entrytype"."old_id", "pages_entrytype"."old_table", 
"pages_entrytype"."parent_id", "pages_entrytype"."lft", 
"pages_entrytype"."rght", "pages_entrytype"."tree_id", 
"pages_entrytype"."level", "pages_entrytype"."slug", 
"pages_entrytype"."bookable", "pages_entrytype"."icon", 
"pages_entrytype"."icon_hover" FROM "pages_entrytype" WHERE 
UPPER("pages_entrytype"."name"::text) = UPPER('accommodation'). 
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of 
transaction block.
STATEMENT:  SELECT c.relname FROM pg_catalog.pg_clasLEFT JOIN 
pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace WHERE c.relkind IN ('r', 
'v', '') AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast') AND 
pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
LOG:  could not receive data from client: An existing connection was 
forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

I have ensured lazy loading in my models.

Comment: General remark: consider updating your Django, 1.5 is *very old*.

Comment: Jojo noted. Will there be if any anticipated repercussion on my app as a consequence of updating?